# Doctrine ODM / MongoDB: index on embedded documents

Tags: doctrine-odm

In my app I embed two documents with different names but same targetDocument

```
# yml mapping
Content\Post:
    type: document
    embedOne:
        facebook:
            targetDocument: Content\PostEmbed
        twitter:
            targetDocument: Content\PostEmbed
```

where the embedded document has a field `value` with index

```
Content\PostEmbed:
    type: embeddedDocument
    fields:
        value:
            type: int
            index:
                order: desc
```

My problems is that when I run the update command of MongoDb ODM, only the index on `facebook.value` is created, and no index is created for `twitter.value`

Of course I can create it manually, but I was wondering if there is a special syntax for it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the alternate syntax for the yaml markup?

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/yml-mapping.html

```
Content\Post:
  type: document
  facebook:
    embedded: true
    type: one
    targetDocument: Content\PostEmbed
  twitter:
    embedded: true
    type: one
    targetDocument: Content\PostEmbed
```